# How to create a navbar like the one in Stuff.tv

Tags: html, css, header, navbar, sticky

I wanted to create a navbar using html and css like the one in http://stuff.tv/ I already have made navbar which can stick to the top even when scrolled, but I wanted to create one in which when the user reaches the navbar, it sticks on top even while scrolling.

Here's the code in html for my navbar:

```
<div id="menu" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css reference:

```
#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #262626;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 50px #5E5E5E;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: You need to use jQuery for this, and need to change toggle the class accordingly like say for example `if( $(this).scrollTop() > 100px )`

Comment: Thanks! That was very useful...but I just wanted to know if there's a way to do it through html5?